# Issue to change the background of a menu item when active

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to adapt a piece of code to meet my needs, unfortunately I can not achieve exactly what I want.

I'd like the first menu item (soins 1) to be displayed by default with a "aqua" background and white font and the other menu items (the non-active ones) with a red background.

Then when I click on the other menu items I'd that "aqua" background to be applied to the active one (the non-active menu items would be red).

I'm struggling to find what needs to be modified in my CSS code or in the JS code. If you click on the JSFiddle link you will have a better understanding of what I'm trying to explain. Many thanks for your help.

http://jsfiddle.net/rk8rmwca/

HTML:

```
<div id="carte-des-soins">
    <ul>
        <li><span class="menu-items"><a href="#" data-region="soins-1"> Soins 1</a></span>

        </li>
        <li><span class="menu-items"><a href="#" data-region="soins-2"> Soins 2</a></span>

        </li>
        <li><span class="menu-items"><a href="#" data-region="soins-3"> Soins 3</a></span>

        </li>
        <li><span class="menu-items"><a href="#" data-region="soins-4"> Soins 4</a></span>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="description-des-soins">
    <div id="soins-1" class="textzone">
        <p>Soins 1 blablabla</p>
    </div>
    <div id="soins-2" class="textzone">
        <p>Soins 2 blablabla</p>
    </div>
    <div id="soins-3" class="textzone">
        <p>Soins 3 blablabla</p>
    </div>
    <div id="soins-4" class="textzone">
        <p>Soins 4 blablabla</p>
    </div>
</div>
<p></p>
<br>
<p></p>
<br>
<p></p>
<br>
```

CSS:

```
#carte-des-soins {
    text-align: center;
}
#carte-des-soins ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding:0;
}
#carte-des-soins li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 10px;
    background: red;
}
#carte-des-soins li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
}
#description-des-soins {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
#soins-1, #soins-2, #soins-3, #soins-4 {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding: 5px 20px 20px 20px;
    color: #333;
    font: 12px'Open Sans', "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1px;
}
#soins-2, #soins-3, #soins-4 {
    display: none;
}
#soins-2 p {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#soins-1 p {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
#soins-1 a {
    color: #3A7CDB;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#soins-1 a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.menu-items a:first').css({
        'color': '#fff',
            'background': 'aqua',
            'padding': '20px'
    });

    $('.menu-items a').click(function () {
        var region = $(this).attr('data-region');


        $('.menu-items a').css({
            'color': '#fff',
                'background': 'red',
                'padding': '20px'
        });

        $(this).css({
            'color': '#fff',
                'background': 'aqua',
                'padding': '20px'
        });

        $('.textzone:visible').stop().fadeOut(500, function () {
            $('#' + region).fadeIn(500);
        });

        return false;

    });

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe **[this works](http://jsfiddle.net/rk8rmwca/1/)** the way you intended.

I've taken the colour and padding declarations out of the JS and applied them with CSS. In general you should try to avoid setting any CSS with JavaScript if you can help it, but instead use JavaScript to toggle classes on elements which will bring about the same effect.

```
#carte-des-soins li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-align:center;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's great, thanks a lot for your help! If I want the color transition to be smoother, should I use CSS transitions or do this via JS? Or do I need both in this case? Many thanks

Comment: If it's purely stylistic, you should always look for a CSS solution **first**. In your specific case, who cares if in IE8 it doesn't smoothly transition, *it still works*. Look at using `transition: background-color 0.5s ease`, apply it to the element above and it should work.